# Not sure why Angular is complaining about Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MenuItem'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular17

Angular is failing to compile because of the following error and I'm really confused as to why.

```
error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MenuItem'.

4     <menu-item item={{item}}></menu-item>
                 ~~~~

  apps/angular-monorepo/src/app/app.component.ts:10:16
    10   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Why is it complaining that item is of type 'string' when I specified that item is of type MenuItem or undefined

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NxWelcomeComponent, RouterModule, MenuItemComponent],
  selector: 'angular-monorepo-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-monorepo';
  menu: MenuItem[] = [
    {id: 101,category: 'appetizer', name:'french toast', price: 10.00},
    {id: 201,category: 'entree',sub_category:"rice",name:'pork', price: 10.00},
    {id: 301,category: 'drinks',name:'tea', price: 10.00},
    {id: 401,category: 'dessert',name:'affogato', price: 10.00},
  ]
}
//app.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<h1>POS</h1>
@for (item of menu; track item.id) {
    <menu-item item={{item}}></menu-item>
}



@Component({
  selector: 'menu-item',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './menu-item.component.html',
  styleUrl: './menu-item.component.scss',
})
export class MenuItemComponent {
  constructor() {

  }
  @Input({required: true}) item: MenuItem | undefined = undefined;
  
  @Output() itemSelectedEvent = new EventEmitter<number>();
}

//menu-item.component.html
@if (item) {
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
}


//menu-item.type.ts
export type MenuItem = {
    id: number,
    category: ItemCategory,
    sub_category?: string,
    name: string,
    price: number
  }
```

I expect item would be of type MenuItem like I specified

Comment: it should be ` <menu-item [item]="item"></menu-item>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets, **[]**, cause Angular to evaluate the right-hand side of the assignment as a dynamic expression.

so like this, you will set item properly

```
  <menu-item [item]="item"></menu-item>
```

Without the brackets, Angular treats the right-hand side as a string literal and sets the property to that static value.

https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property